# Filtering html fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have read about filtering table plugins. What I'm searching for is like this popup window.

[image: popup]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7227/7294670838_a2244899bf.jpg))</sub>

When the user starts typing in the search-box, the relevant channel/category (as selected on previous dropdown box) should filter up. Also some animated loading action should happen while the filter process is going on.

I am looking for jQuery plugins which will make my filter-job easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is to ambigous to have a plugin for it. Just do something like this:

```
function filter($rows, category, search) {
     $rows.each(function() {
          if (category == ($("td:eq(2)", this).text() || category == "all") &&  (search. === "" || $("td:eq(1)", this).text().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
               $(":checkbox", this).removeAttr("disabled");
               $(this).show();
          }
          else
               $(this).hide(function(){
                   $(":checkbox", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
               });
     });
}


$("select.category").change(function() {
     filter ($(this).closest("form").find("tr"), $(this).val(), $(this).closest("form").find("input.search").val());
});

$("input.search").keyUp(function() {
     filter ($(this).closest("form").find("tr"), $(this).closest("form").find("select.catagory").val(), $(this).val()); 
});
```

You may need to make a few adjustments in order to make it work with the exact format of html.

### Update to make it into a *PLUGIN*

```
$.fn.filter_table = function(options) {
    options = $.extend(options, {
         show: $.noop(), //Callback when a row get shown
         hide: $.noop(), // Callback when a row gets hidden
         entries: "table tr", // Selector of items to filter.
         map: {} //Required parameter
        //TODO Add default ajustment parameters here to remove ambiguity and assumptions.      
    });

    return this.each(function() {
        var form = this;

        function each(callback) {
            for (var selector in options.map) {
                 var check = options.map[selector];
                 $(selector, form).each(function(){
                     callback.call(this, check);
                 });  
            }
        }

        function show(row) {
            if (!$(row).is(":visible")) {
               options.show.apply(row);
               $(row).show();
            }
        }

        function hide(row) {
            if ($(row).is(":visible"))
               $(row).hide(options.hide);
        }

        function run_filter() {
            $(options.entries, form).each(function() {
               var row = this, matched = true;

               each(function(check) {
                   matched &= check.call(this, row);
               });

               matched ? show(this) : hide(this);
            })
        }

        //Bind event handlers:

        each(function() {
           $(this).bind($(this).is(":text") ? "keyup" : "change", run_filter);
        });

    });
};
```

You can use this plugin as follows:

```
$("form").filter_table({
    map: {
       //These callback define if a row was matched:
       "select.category": function(row) {
            //this refers to the field, row refers to the row being checked.
            return $(this).val() == "all" || $(this).val() == $("td:eq(2)", row).text();
        },
        "input.search": function(row) {
            return $(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == $("td:eq(1)", row).text();
        }
    },

    entries: "tr:has(:checkbox)", //Filter all rows that contain a checkbox.

    show: function() {
        $(":checkbox", this).removeAttr("disabled");
    },

    hide: function() {
        $(":checkbox", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Okay it should work once it was debugged. I haven't tested it. I think that part is up to you.

Comment: I agree, its not that much complicated. but if somebody has already written some good plugin, why not utilize his effort !

Comment: @tusar because it is to localized to have a robust plugin ready for you.

Comment: ya... but please add some plugin links to your answer. I am really afraid to implement this huge task myself...

Comment: @tusar, I think I've done 90% of the work there already. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I really appreciate your help @d_inevitable , I've +1ed all answers, but you know, I have many more popup window like this on the same page. So I was thinking , some plugin may be helpful...

Comment: Ok well let me convert that into a plugin then... But as I said, it is ambigous due to the input-field data association.

Comment: that will be a great help. I donno how to express my respect about your effort. I will wait for your plugin to get completed. Thank you ! Thank you ! Thank you !

Comment: @tusar, your welcome, but plugins are not much of a big deal in jquery. let me know if you you need some parts explained.

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="filterForm">
    <input type="text" id="filterBox">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>

<div id="checkboxContainer">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox123"> Checkbox 123</label>
</div>
```

You could do something like...

```
//Set variables so we only have to find each element once
var filterForm = $('#filterForm');
var filterBox = $('#filterBox');
var checkboxContainer = $('#checkboxContainer');

//Override the form submission
filterForm.submit(function() {

    //Filter by what the label contains
    checkboxContainer.find('label').each(function() {

        //If the value of filterBox is NOT in the label
        if ($(this).indexOf(filterBox.val()) == -1) {

            //Hide the label (and the checkbox since it's inside the label)
            $(this).hide();

        } else {

            //Show it in case it was hidden before
            $(this).show();

        }
    });

    //Prevent the form from submitting
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thank you ! but I didnt ask for jQuery code. can you post some useful jQuery plugin links ?

Comment: I just wrote the plugin for you ;)

Comment: Can you please choose my answer since I took the time to do this for you? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [tablesorterfilter](https://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter) plugin to achieve what you need

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/xm3My/1/)

And also please have a look at http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are many options out there. Here is a good place to start: http://www.wokay.com/technology/32-useful-jquery-filter-and-sort-data-plugins-62033.html

Filtering like this isn't incredibly complicated. It may be worth looking at the source of a couple plugins that come close to what you want and then try to write your own. You'll learn a lot more if you do it yourself!